# input variable into python call subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, call

I have a small python snippet that calls a larger program (I did not write the larger one).

```
call(['function1', file1,  file2,  'data.labels=abc, xyz'])
```

The above works.

```
input ='abc, xyz'
```

Now I want to input "abc, xyz" as a variable holding this value

```
call(['function1', file1,  file2,  'data.labels=input'])
```

but it does not work.

How can I pass a variable value into variable data.labels within call subprocess.

Comment: A more specific question might be, "how do I take the string `'abc, xyz'` and somehow get the string `'data.labels=abc, xyz'`"? The answer isn't really specific to `call` at all, just ordinary string manipulation.

Comment: @Kevin: It is specific to `subprocess.call()` on Windows where `CreateProcess()` is used to start the child process that accepts a single string as a command, see `subprocess.list2cmdline()`. In other words, you can't pass arbitrary unescaped values on Windows because `list2cmdline()` doesn't cover all possible cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
call(['function1', file1,  file2,  'data.labels=%s' % input])
```

Comment: [`'data.labels=' + input`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25753183/4279) seems like a more natural code.

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
call(['function1', file1,  file2,  'data.labels=' + input)
```

If for some reason, input is not a string.

```
call(['function1', file1,  file2,  'data.labels=' + str(input) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the same:

```
call(['function1', file1,  file2,  'data.labels={0}'.format(input)])
```